# how to call function that is inside a function ready()?

Tags: javascript, html, function, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a function ready(e) which inside hold a canvas and some other function.
I want to make an action outside the canvas to call an function inside ready(e). How can I do that? thanks very much!!

Below is a simplified version of my code.. I want to call arraytwo() outside function ready(e)...

```
function ready(e)
{
    var canvas;
    var canvasWidth;
    var canvasHeight;
    var ctx;
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    canvasWidth = 1100  ;
    canvasHeight = 1200;
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    function arraytwo() 
    {alert("arraytwo");}
}
arraytwo();
```

EDIT: Sorry i should have clarify, the function/information/data I use in arraytwo will have to be used in the canvas. alert() is just an example. so I can't put it outside ready(e).

EDIT2: there is one line of code before function ready(e). hope this information is useful :(

```
this.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ready, true);
```

EDIT3: and this is the code for the canvas in html

```
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: You have to declare arraytwo() in the public namespace. By placing it inside the function ready() it only exists in the scope of ready()

Comment: Thanks how do I declare arraytwo() in public namespace?? (sorry newbie in javascript)

Comment: Just mean un nest it outside of ready(){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this case "arraytwo" function is a private function you can call it by returning it or by using  [Closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) pattern

```
    function ready(e)
    {
        var canvas;
        var ctx;
       // canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      // ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      return {
                arraytwo:function(){
                  alert("arraytwo");
                }
             }
    }

v = ready() // call your outer function 
v.arraytwo()// call your closures function
```

Comment: please add canvas code(html, js) in you question so i can check

Comment: Thanks I have added some more code. Hope its useful!

Comment: Thanks. somehow mine just does not work maybe there's something wrong with my other bit of my code.
 But thanks so much for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just move your function outside of the `ready` scope?

```
function ready(e)
{
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
}

function arraytwo(){
    alert("arraytwo");
}

arraytwo();
```

Comment: Sorry i should have clarify, the function/information/data I use in arraytwo will have to be used in the canvas. alert() is just an example. so I can't put it outside ready(e).

Comment: In that case @Shailendra Sharma solution has the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function ready(e)
{
    var canvas;
    var ctx;
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    function arraytwo() 
    {
      alert("arraytwo");
    }
    ready.arraytwo=arraytwo;
}
ready.arraytwo();
```

While i stated above the reasons you shouldnt do this. You can build your object of ready by adding arraytwo as a child by adding

```
ready.arraytwo=arraytwo;
```

which will make this vissible at the global scope.

Answer (score -1):

You can use events for this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events

Call event on canvas outside block, and listen for it in block.

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare arraytwo() in the public namespace. By placing it inside the function ready() it only exists in the scope of ready() There is no reason to declare a function inside a function unless it is only being used in the context and scope of the parent function. Such as if you had two functions both with a method of the same name that were different and wanted them to access variables within the scope of the parent function then you would nest them. In this instance nesting is not the correct way to go.

```js
var canvas;
var ctx;


    function ready(e)
    {

        canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    }

    function arraytwo()  
    {
       alert("arraytwo");
      return arrayTwoData;
    }

    var arrayTwoData=arraytwo();
```

Also would like to point out that it is better practice to use window.onload=function(){arrayTwo();};

Comment: Sorry i should have clarify, the function/information/data I use in arraytwo will have to be used in the canvas. alert() is just an example. so I can't put it outside ready(e).

Comment: You can by passing arguments to it, returning data back from it or simply declaring the necessary variables in the public namespace.

Comment: I edited the code above to show that you can make the data you need accessible globally. This isn't the best approach but without seeing your code and data flow it's the best I can recommend.